# Using plugin outside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I have a plugin (EZ form calculator https://codecanyon.net/item/ez-form-calculator-wordpress-plugin/7595334 ) used in my Wordpress installation. With this plugin I can make forms including a calculator function. For the forms you can use a shortcode to place it in a page or post. I want to use this shortcode in a simple .php file because I want to have the form inside here.

I figured out how to use Wordpress elements outside the WP-environment, but for some reason the form is not working and Chromes gives a `500 ERROR`. Once I delete the last line, I can see the `get_header();` is showing the header in the page. So that will say the Wordpress functions are working.

How do I get the plugin working?

```html
require_once 'wp2/wp-blog-header.php';

get_header();

echo 'new content outside WordPress';
echo do_shortcode('[ezfc id='2' /]');
```